# Magento 2.4.2 : Disabled Products are visible in Frontend

Tags: catalog, visibility, enable-disable

Products, that are disabled in our backend, are still shown in the frontend.
Even after changing the visibility to "**not visible individually**" or just **"catalog"**, they still appear through the search function in our shop.

We already tried clearing the **cache** and **reindexing**.
Is there another option?

The products were originally synched from our ERP system, but we changed the settings in our ERP system to "not available" and "not active" as well. - still no change

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have attributes saved on store level?

Comment: Do you mean the Attribute Sets? @VictorTihonchuk

Comment: No. I mean that maybe you have status/visibility attributes for store for your product.